# How can i enable/disable a button filed in balckberry OS 5, Or How can i add or delete control on a button field in blackberry OS 5

Tags: blackberry

```
public void setEditable(final boolean enabled) 
{
    if (!enabled) 
    {
        _bitmap = _disabledBitmap;
    }
    if (enabled) 
    {
        _bitmap = _noFocusBitmap;
    }
    invalidate();
    super.setEditable(enabled);
}
```

I use the method in OS6  `setEnabled(boolean flag)` it is working fine. But it does not supports in OS-5, In Os5 i try to use the `setEditable(boolean flag)` but not working. Please Help..

Thanks A lot in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I use following code to enable/disable button

```
//when you dont want control of button field use
_buttonField.setChangeListener(null); 


//when you want control of button field use
_buttonField.setChangeListener(<your change listener>);


//if you want to remove button from manager use 
manager.delete(_buttonField);


//if you want to add button to manager use 
manager.add(_buttonField);
```

Comment: thanks for reply,but not match my requirements, i have to create a button Field as the radio button Field and work as radio button behavior, and i also have to change the button img on click and others button are unchanged. Only one is selected at a time and its image must be changed.   Plz help

Comment: Do you want to mean that you are trying to make a **group of Radio Buttons** among which if one is selected then the others are unselected automatically?